# Transiting via Shanghai Pudong International Airport

Tags: transit, transit-visas, china, pvg

i intend to travel to Osaka, Japan via Shanghai Pudong International Airport on China Eastern Airlines.

Since i only have a 4.5 hours transit at the Shanghai Pudong International Airport, do i need a Transit Visa in this regard? or can i do an Airside/Direct Transit at Shanghai Pudong International Airport without crossing/entering the Border Control?

Comment: I am in reference with Shanghai Pudong International Airport specifically

Comment: @engqureshi The answers to the other question don't seem to be specific to any airport. Do you have any reason to believe that Shanghai Pudong is different?

Comment: @DavidRicherby ... there has been conflicting information about the transit procedures at Shanghai Pudong International Airport and this has made me raise this particular question